# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appVerificationDisabledForTesting')

Tags: dart

Flutter firebase login with phone number verifyPhoneNumber throwing error.

I tried to log with phone number and otp but it is unable to send otp and throwing error.

Unable to log in firebase

Unable to verify number in firebase

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.